# "Sans faire des pauses" ou "sans faire une pause" ?

Tags: grammaire, articles

Quelqu'un pourrait-il me dire si la phrase suivante est correcte :

> À mon âge, il est difficile de marcher plus que cinq metres sans faire
>   des pauses.

Est-ce que ce serait mieux de dire sans faire *une* pause ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> À mon âge, il est difficile de marcher plus **de** cinq m**è**tres sans faire **de** pauses.

Dire *sans faire des pauses* est aussi possible, mais moins littéraire.

*Sans faire une pause* est en revanche possible quel que soit le registre, mais avec une signification qui peut être différente. Une seule pause serait possible quelle que soit la longueur du déplacement, ce qui n'est sûrement pas le sens souhaité.